# How to send serial write command from raspberry pi3 to FTDI using Python?

Tags: python, pi-3, serial

I'm using *Raspberry Pi3 under Rasbian OS*. My goal is to connect the RPi USB to the FTDI and send serial write command to the FTDI using Python:

```
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print(data)
    time.sleep(1)
```

But no data displayed?

And so does the write command no data out?

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is to connect the raspberry pi3 USB to the FTDI and send serial write command

I don't use python but I guarantee **this is a read, not a write**:

```
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print(data)
```

Unless whatever is on the other end of the FTDI cable is *sending data to the pi* then this will do nothing but wait for something that never happens.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your FTDI chip is probably mounted under /dev/ttyUSBx, not ttyACM0.

Second, writing is done using serial.write(buffer) function. If you want to test communication with the FTDI chip itself (whether UART works or not), connect a jumper across TX and RX pins of the module you have. This will print out anything you send to chip